# javax.servlet.jsp.JspTagException: Don't know how to iterate over supplied "items" in &lt;forEach&gt

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, jsp

What I am want to do is to add a record to a table and then to display that newly added record in a jsp page.

Here is what I tried:

Controller:

```
@Controller
public class UserController {
    
    @Autowired
    UserRepository userRepo;
    
    @RequestMapping("/adduser")    
    public String userform(Model m){    
        m.addAttribute("command", new Users());  
        return "adduser";
    }
    
    @RequestMapping("/saveuser")
    public String save(@ModelAttribute("user") Users user,Model model){    
        userRepo.save(user);
        model.addAttribute("user", user);
        return "forward:/user";   
    }
    
    @RequestMapping("/user")
    public String user(Model model) {
       
         return "user";
    }
```

And the jsp page:

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<%@ taglib prefix="spring" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>
<html lang="en">
<head>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"
 href="webjars/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<c:url value="/css/main.css" var="jstlCss" />
<link href="${jstlCss}" rel="stylesheet" />

</head>
<body>
 <div class="container">
  <div class="starter-template">
   <h1>Product List</h1>
   <table
    class="table table-striped table-hover table-condensed table-bordered">
    <tr>
     <th>Id</th>
     <th>Color</th>
     <th>Gender</th>
     <th>Category</th>
    </tr>
    <c:forEach var="u" items="${user}">
     <tr>
      <td>${u.userid}</td>
      <td>${u.username}</td>
      <td>${u.userphone}</td>
      <td>${u.useremail}</td>
     </tr>
    </c:forEach>
   </table>
  </div>

 </div>

 <script type="text/javascript"
  src="webjars/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Upon running the code the record is getting added successfully but It is not getting displayed instead I am getting the error mentioned in the title.

What to do to make it work?

Answer (score 0):

```
@RequestMapping("/user")
public List<User> user(Model model) {
     ...
     return ...;
}
```

`${user}` is the result of that method `user`.

```
<c:forEach var="u" items="${user}">
```

The `forEach` tag requires as `items`something `Iterable`.

In fact the name should have been plural: `users`.

You need something like

```
public class User {
    int userid;
    String username;
    String userphone;
    String useremail;
}

  <td>${u.userid}</td>
  <td>${u.username}</td>
  <td>${u.userphone}</td>
  <td>${u.useremail}</td>
```